# Why did I get this indentation Error in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation, nano

Hello I am having an indentation error on python 2.7
My program looks like this:

```
import sys, os
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from re import split

def GetProcesses(Clean=True):
    #
    if Clean == True:
        #
        #
        x = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = x.communicate()
        print(out)
        print(out.split("\n"))
        print("--------------")
        Processes = out.split("\n")
        print(Processes)
        print("------")
        print(Processes[0])
        print("----------")
        Header = Processes[0]
        Process_list = Processes.remove(Processes[0])
        return((Header, Process_list))
    #
    else:
        #
        #
        if Clean == True: #added problem so future SE users can see it
        x = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = x.communicate()
        return(out)
```

I am not understanding the error, I have tried de-denting everyline 1 space, indenting back to the originals, and adding 1 space but it always says that it either expects an indent, or unexpected indent. P.S I am using only spaces.

Actual Error:

```
  File "MemoryHandling.py", line 31
    x = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I have check several online questions/sources (mainly SE) for this error (below) both during and before asking this question, i found that they were case specific, downvoted / not answered, or were not usefull: 
-- [Python Indentation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946933/python-indentation-error) # i am using spaces 
-- [Python 2.7 Indentation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090495/python-2-7-indentation-error) # i have manually checked indentation multiple times, and tried using the tab key 
-- [Unexpected indentation error, but indentation looks correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559358/unexpected-indentation-error-but-indentation-looks-correct/34559388) # once again not using tabs and spaces 
-- [Code Indent Error, code is indented?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254338/code-indent-error-code-is-indented) # not answered (bug?) 
-- [Python Indentation Error when there is no indent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416297/python-indentation-error-when-there-is-no-indent-error) # once more not using tabs and spaces

Comment: did you try running with `python -tt yourscript.py`?  This will throw an error if you've accidentally mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: After `if Clean == True:` you seem to be missing tabs (probably on the next 3 lines after that statement)

Comment: It does throw an error, but i have not used tab... i will re - write it

Comment: tabs or whitespaces... What I mean is that the `x = subprocess...` has to be indented (can't be at the same level than the `if`)

Comment: However, that code doesn't make sense, since the first line of the `GetProcess` function already checks `if Clean == True`. Then you have an `else` (which will only be hit if `Clean` is `False`) and within that, you check again `if Clean == True`, which we already know it's not gonna happen because you already checked it on the top of your function

Comment: Indentation errors aside, why do you have `if Clean == True` followed by `else: if Clean == True`?  That makes no logical sense.

Comment: yes that worked.... the cringe is real........ how do i mark an answer as a comment

Comment: You have to wait for somebody to post the comment as an answer. Also, instead of using the ` character a bunch of times, you can start each line you want to be a contiguous code block with 4 spaces if you would like.

Comment: oh thank you i added the clean == true for debugging i dont know why...

Comment: `i found that they were case specific, downvoted / not answered, or were not useful` - I think you can see why!

Comment: "i have manually checked indentation multiple times, and tried using the tab key " - in your own words: how much indentation did you count in front of the line? How much did you believe there should have been, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys, os
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from re import split

#Actual Code:
def GetProcesses(Clean):
    #
    if Clean == True:
        #
        #
        x = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = x.communicate()
        print(out)
        print(out.split("\n"))
        print("--------------")
        Processes = out.split("\n")
        print(Processes)
        print("------")
        print(Processes[0])
        print("----------")
        Header = Processes[0]
        Process_list = Processes.remove(Processes[0])
        return((Header, Process_list))
    #
    else:
        #
        #
        x = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = x.communicate()
        return(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here. After `if` part, there is no indentation provided.

```
else:
    if Clean == True: #added problem so future SE users can see it
        x = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = x.communicate()
        return(out)
```